# Subsetting Data Creating NA rows

Tags: r

I've been working with this large dataset (19 variables with any combination of ints, strings, and floats, with a mix of complete observations and observations with empty variables). I have subsetted them into different data frames based on date, and am getting some unexpected results. My work so far:

```
# reading in data; at this point there are no rows that are completely
# full of na values
     Data <- read.csv("Data.csv", stringsAsFactors = FALSE)

# removing data I don't want to look at; I'm sure this isn't the
# most efficient way to do this but it works
     Data2 <- Data[!(Data$Event.Clearance.Group=="TRAFFIC RELATED CALLS") & 
                      !(Data$Event.Clearance.Group=="FALSE ALARMS") &
                      !(Data$Event.Clearance.Group=="FALSE ALACAD") &
                      !(Data$Event.Clearance.Group=="HARBOR CALLS") &
                      !(Data$Event.Clearance.Group=="NULL"),]

# reformatting the date into new col to easily subset
     Data2$Date <- as.Date(as.character(Data2$Event.Clearance.Date), "%m/%d/%Y")

# Subsetting Data into years; after I do this the subsets suddenly have 
# tons of NA values. I do this for each year from 2011 - 2015
     Data2011 <- Data2[Data2$Date >= as.Date("2011-01-01") & 
                      Data2$Date <as.Date("2012-01-01"),]
```

What's even more strange (or maybe not) is that every subset has the exact same number of NA rows, despite different sizes. Each one has exactly 14198 empty rows. What in the world is going on? Is this an issue or can I just 
remove those rows from the subsets and move on? I don't want to be changing the data at all, but if all that's happening is empty rows are being generated I'm not too concerned about it, I just don't want to be unwittingly changing the data in ways I'm not aware of. Any insights would be appreciated!

Comment: Maybe use `myYearList <- split(Data2, format(Data2$Date, "%Y"))` to split the data by years.

Comment: That worked beautifully, thank you. Apparently I just generate 14198 empty rows every time with my other method... My question still stands though, why are these empty rows being generated?

Answer (score 2):

Do your Data2$Date has NA values ?
What is the result of this ?

```
    sum(is.na(Data2$Date >= as.Date("2011-01-01") & 
                          Data2$Date <as.Date("2012-01-01")))
```

Having NA in a vector that should be only TRUE or FALSE will cause rows of NA to appear in your answer.